# Looking for duplicate values in a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

The assignment I am working on requires that I create a Sudoku game without using any classes, methods, encapsulation, etc. I am having trouble validating that the values my user inputs into either my "fourArray" or "nineArray" contains no duplicate values. So far I have been trying to use a nested for-loop in order to iterate through both the columns and rows of either array. For example, I have been trying to include the following piece of code at the end of my program to determine if there are any duplicate values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < fourArray.length; j++)
        if (fourArray[i] == fourArray[j]) {
            System.out.println("No Sudoku");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sudoku!);
        }
 }
```

However this is not working. I want to iterate through the arrays to find any duplicate any values, and if there are none, then print out "Sudoku!" If there is any duplicate values, then I want to print out "Sudoku!" Do I need to sort the array at all? Or is there some method I am not aware of? I have included my program. Thank you for your time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sudoku {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int boardSize = -1;
        int[][] fourArray = { {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0} };
        int[][] nineArray = { {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} }; 
        while (true)
        {
            Scanner boardsizeOption = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please select a board size:" + "\n" + "1) 4x4" + "\n" + "2) 9x9");
            boardSize = boardsizeOption.nextInt();
            if (boardSize == 1 || boardSize == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (boardSize == 1) { //still need to build complete board 
            int i, j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < fourArray.length; j++)
                    System.out.print(fourArray[i][j] + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        } else if (boardSize == 2) { 
            int i, j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < nineArray.length; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < nineArray.length; j++)
                    System.out.print(nineArray[i][j] + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
        int dataSelection = -1;     
        while (true)
        {
            Scanner rowColumn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please select which way you would like to enter the values:" + "\n" + "1) row" + "\n" + "2) columnn");
            dataSelection = rowColumn.nextInt();
            if (dataSelection == 1 || dataSelection == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        //Entering by ROWS
        //This is for a 4x4 board size using rows
        if (dataSelection == 1) {
            if (boardSize == 1) {
                int row = 1;
                while (row < 5) {
                    String row1Values4x4 = "-1";
                    while (true) {
                        Scanner firstRow4x4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.println("Please enter four values using commas for row " + row); //this needs to loop
                        row1Values4x4 = firstRow4x4.next();
                        row1Values4x4 = row1Values4x4.replaceAll(" ",""); //this is in case user enters numbers with spaces
                        if (row1Values4x4.length() == 7) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    String strArray[] = row1Values4x4.split(",");
                    int arraySidesInteger[] = new int[strArray.length];
                    for (int i = 0;  i < strArray.length;  i++) {
                        arraySidesInteger[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
                    }
                    fourArray[row-1] = arraySidesInteger;
                    for (int i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < fourArray.length; j++)
                            System.out.print(fourArray[i][j] + " ");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    row++;
                }
                //This is for a 9x9 board size using rows 
                } else { 
                    int row = 1;
                    while (row < 10) {
                        String row1Values9x9 = "-1";
                        while (true) {
                            Scanner firstRow9x9 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            System.out.println("Please enter nine values using commas for row " + row); //this needs to loop
                            row1Values9x9 = firstRow9x9.next();
                            row1Values9x9 = row1Values9x9.replaceAll(" ",""); //this is in case user enters numbers with spaces
                            if (row1Values9x9.length() == 17) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        String strArray[] = row1Values9x9.split(",");
                        int arraySidesInteger[] = new int[strArray.length];
                        for (int i = 0;  i < strArray.length;  i++) {
                            arraySidesInteger[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
                        }
                        nineArray[row-1] = arraySidesInteger;
                        for (int i = 0; i < nineArray.length; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < nineArray.length; j++)
                                System.out.print(nineArray[i][j] + " ");
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        row++;
                    }
                }
            //Entering by COLUMNS
            //This is for 4x4 board size using columns 
            } else { 
                if (boardSize == 1) {
                    int column = 1;
                    while (column < 5) {
                        String column1Values4x4 = "-1"; 
                        while (true) {
                            Scanner firstColumn4x4 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            System.out.println("Please enter four values using commas for column " + column);
                            column1Values4x4 = firstColumn4x4.next();
                            column1Values4x4 = column1Values4x4.replaceAll(" ","");
                            if (column1Values4x4.length() == 7) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        String strArray[] = column1Values4x4.split(",");
                        int arraySidesInteger[] = new int[strArray.length];
                        for (int i = 0;  i < strArray.length;  i++) {
                            arraySidesInteger[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < arraySidesInteger.length; i++) {
                            fourArray[i][column-1] = arraySidesInteger[i];
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < fourArray.length; j++)
                                System.out.print(fourArray[i][j] + " ");
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        column++;
                    }
                //This is for a 9x9 board size using columns
                } else { 
                    int column = 1;
                    while (column < 10) {
                        String column1Values9x9 = "-1";
                        while (true) {
                            Scanner firstColumn9x9 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            System.out.println("Please enter nine values using commas for column " + column);
                            column1Values9x9 = firstColumn9x9.next();
                            column1Values9x9 = column1Values9x9.replaceAll(" ","");
                            //row1Values4x4 = row1Values4x4.replaceAll(",","");
                            if (column1Values9x9.length() == 17) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        String strArray[] = column1Values9x9.split(",");
                        int arraySidesInteger[] = new int[strArray.length];
                        for (int i = 0;  i < strArray.length;  i++) {
                            arraySidesInteger[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < arraySidesInteger.length; i++) {
                            nineArray[i][column-1] = arraySidesInteger[i];
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < nineArray.length; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < nineArray.length; j++)
                                System.out.print(nineArray[i][j] + " ");


                    System.out.println();
                    }
                    column++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++) {
                for(int j = i + 1; j < fourArray.length; j++) {
                    if(fourArray[i] == fourArray[j]) {
                        System.out.println("No Sudoku");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Sudoku!");
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it not run? Give the wrong output? Throw an error?

Comment: So your teacher gave you an assignment in java ... and doesn't want you to use classes?

Comment: I'd love to see your working Java program without any classes.

Comment: .......public class Sudoku {

Comment: My program does not recognize what I am trying to do. It just stops running right after I input the values into the array. Does not present an error or anything.

Comment: @aaronman Well technically, of course you need classes but I was trying to refer to using methods and what not.

Comment: @Kon Well of course its not. I am aware of that. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Your professor seriously wants you to code a Sudoku game without using classes or methods? Why would s/he have you practice poor habits?

Comment: @Kon functional java ;)

Comment: @Kon I believe our next assignment is to convert our program into different classes. For some reason, he wants us to practice writing the basics or something. Idk. But I agree, it would be easier to use classes of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's homework, I'm going to minimize code, but I think you'll be fine to figure it out if you have some more info about 2D arrays, some of which is fairly tricky:

- Since `fourArray` is an array of arrays, `fourArray[i]` refers to an array (you can think of it as the i-th row of your 2-D array).
- To access an individual integers within your array of arrays, use `fourArray[i][j]`.
- If you do myArray1 == myArray2 (as your code essentially does at the moment), it does NOT compare the contents; rather, it checks if they are actually the same array (as would happen if you said `myArray1 = myArray2` first).
- If you did want to compare the contents of two arrays, you can use `Arrays.equals(myArray1, myArray2)`.
- As follows from the above points, `fourArray.length` is the size in one dimension; `fourArray[x].length` is the size in the other dimension (where `x` doesn't matter so long as it's between `0` and `fourArray.length - 1`).

**Added in response to comment:** My understanding and assumption is that you are trying to avoid any duplicate values between any of the values contained in the 2-D `fourArray`.  There are a number of solutions.

What might be called the naive solution is to first use a pair of nested `for` loops to go through each value in `fourArray`.  For each of those values, compare it to every other value.  Your intermediate code might look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < fourArray[i].length; j++) {
        // TODO: Compare value at (i,j) to every other point by nesting
        // two more for loops with new iterators (called, e.g., m and n)
        // TODO: If a duplicate is found, either stop searching, or at
        // least mark that a duplicate has been found somehow.
    }
}
```

On one hand, this is a bit inefficient.  On the other, for small 2-D arrays it's still totally trivial computationally, so if it makes sense to you, do it and move on to other problems.

However, I'll submit another idea for your consideration, should you be interested and with the assumption that the allowed values are part of a sequential set (i.e., in typical Sudoku games you have 3x3 boxes within which the allowed values are always 1-9, never higher).  What if you had an array `count[]` that kept track of how many times these known values had occurred?  So all values in it would be initialized to zero.  As you iterated through each spot in the table (as shown in the above code sample), you could use the value found--call it `v`--to increment `count[v]`.  Any value in `count[]` greater than one represents a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having difficulty understanding how to iterate both the rows and columns though. For instance, if I iterate the rows to find duplicates, I must keep fourArray[i] = 0 and fourArray[][k] would continue to iterate in order to find duplicates. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First off, in your entire class code you need to move your Sudoku check down 1 `}` (there should be only 2 after it, the mains and the classes).

The second thing is as you thought, your double for loop is wrong, assuming I understand the problem correctly.  If you want to check every single value against every other value in the grid, this is how I would do it:

```
    boolean sudoku = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < fourArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < fourArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (fourArray[i] == fourArray[j]) {
                sudoku = false;
                break;
            } 
            if (!sudoku){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (sudoku){
        System.out.println("Sudoku!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Sudoku!");
    }
```

Comment: You never index into the 2nd dimension, so there's at least a small bit missing. :)